# How to list Bluetooth Low Energy devices on Android 4.3?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, nexus-4

Does the sample code [from the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) work for anyone? After doing `startLeScan`, the `onLeScan` callback never gets called (Nexus 4, Android 4.3).

Meanwhile, another app that I have installed ([BLE Heart Rate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pribble.htc.ble.hrm&hl=en)) doesn't seem to have any issues finding nearby Bluetooth LE devices (Fitbit One, Polar H7), so I must be missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot to add the `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN` permission. Without this permission, one can still call `startLeScan`,it just won't ever discover any devices!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

Comment: I just found out the same thing today... I would have expected some error when trying startLeScan without permission.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works. Not very well though. (after some tests it will start disconnecting and I need to toggle the bluetooth on <--> off).

Have you missed something? What kind of device you are trying to find?

Comment: Here's the code I am using: https://gist.github.com/ejain/19625986155bf76b85da. I have several BLE devices nearby, and none of them get listed. The other app I mentioned doesn't have any trouble listing the devices and connecting--though there is an issue that once you disconnect, you can no longer reconnect...

Comment: Sample also working for me.  Nexus 4 with Viiiiva HRM doing HR profile is looking good.